# how to get clicked a href link on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mouseover

how to get clicked a href link on mouseover?

i want to get clicked my link on mouseover

what i have to do to make my link get clicked on mouseover

this is my code:

`<a href="www.example.com">link</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like :

```
<a onmouseover="this.click();" href="...">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for achieving this manipulation

```
  $('a').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).click();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery or Style attribute

```
    <a href="" onmouseover="$(this).click()" >Click Me</a> 
    <a href="" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';">Click Me</a>
```